# Is Scribe sticking around for a while?

Tags: grails, scribe

Simple question - I have dabbled with the awesome scribe library before but am now thinking of committing to this for an oauth-dependent production grails app. Is there enough community support to keep this library going with all the API changes the likes of Facebook seem to be doing these days? I'd hate to have to revert to something spring security for oauth but, in the same sentence, would not want to have to keep customising scribe for my own once API changes are released by providers.

I ask this because the core code (which is probably perfectly fine at the moment) is about 4 years old. Is this project here to stay?

Answer (score 1):

With the exception of hearing from the Scribe team it's nearly impossible to answer this question with a simple yes/no.

However, I think it's better to look at it from this perspective to arrive at a valid answer.

1. Does it meet your needs today?
2. Do you have access to the source code?
3. Does it have an active community?
4. Do you have other options if you need to replace it in the future?
5. Should you need to, can you modify the source to meet your own needs in the future?

Given the fact you do have access to the source, and you do have other options I'd say it doesn't really matter if it's going to stick around because you have *options* for the future.

Of course, the answer depends on your own abilities and risk assessment, but I think it would be safe to say you can arrive at an answer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's the same answer I've given myself as a justification :) And of course you're right about all of the above. Bite the bullet and refactor if I must. That would be fine in a community like ruby/php/.net but production grails? Hmm...

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the last bit of your comment. What's the issue with Grails?